# Javascript: import another javascript file

Tags: javascript, import

I have an xState State Machine defined in a MYSM.js. I would like to try importing this javascript file in my app.js file. I have tried every solution and I can't get it to work.

MYSM.js

```
const { createMachine, actions, interpret, assign, interface } = XState;

export interface MYSMContext {
    returnCode: undefined, errorMessage: undefined
}
export const mySM = createMachine({/* code here */});
```

app.js

```
import {mySM} from './MYSM.js'

const newContext = {returnCode: 0; errorMessage: ''};
const dynamicSM = mySM.withContext(newContext);
const myService = interpret(dynamicSM).start();
```

index.html

```
<!-- xState State Machine-->
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/xstate@4/dist/xstate.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/xstate@4/dist/xstate.web.js"></script>

<script type="module" src="~/js/MYSM.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/app.js"></script>
```

In my browser, I'm getting the 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'
How do I import MYSM.js into app.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error should be taken quite literally:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

You are using import statement `import {mySM} from './MYSM.js'` inside `app.js`, which is not a module. But the rule is clear: you cannot use import statement, if it is not inside a module. Change `app.js` to `module` by changing `type` attribute:

```
<script type="module" src="~/js/app.js"></script>
```

---

*Additional notes:*

You can also remove this line of code

```
<script type="module" src="~/js/MYSM.js"></script>
```

since you are already importing `mySM` inside app.js.